# How to reverse summing amount of files of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

In my code, I want to modify my array to have a sum of all child files on each level.
I started by creating a recursive function to walk through the tree.

```js
const data = [
  {
    foldername: "folder1",
    amount_of_files: 123,
    children: [
      {
        foldername: "folder1.1",
        amount_of_files: 3,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        foldername: "folder1.2",
        amount_of_files: 5,
        children: [
          {
            foldername: "folder1.2.1",
            amount_of_files: 20,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    foldername: "folder2",
    amount_of_files: 1,
    children: [
      {
        foldername: "folder2.1",
        amount_of_files: 3,
        children: [
          {
            foldername: "folder2.1.1",
            amount_of_files: 2,
            children: [
              {
                foldername: "folder2.1.1.1",
                amount_of_files: 24,
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        foldername: "folder2.2",
        amount_of_files: 5,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const rec = (input) => {

    input.forEach((e) => {
        console.log(e.foldername, e.amount_of_files);
        if (e.children.length > 0) {
            rec(e.children);
        } else {
            // I reached the deapest point of a branch.
            // Now I need to start cycling back
        }
    })
}

rec(data);
```

The output that I expect looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    foldername: "folder1",
    amount_of_files: 123,
    sum_children_files: 28,
    children: [
      {
        foldername: "folder1.1",
        amount_of_files: 3,
        sum_children_files: 25,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        foldername: "folder1.2",
        amount_of_files: 5,
        sum_children_files: 20,
        children: [
          {
            foldername: "folder1.2.1",
            amount_of_files: 20,
            sum_children_files: 0,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    foldername: "folder2",
    amount_of_files: 1,
    sum_children_files: 32,
    children: [
      {
        foldername: "folder2.1",
        amount_of_files: 3,
        sum_children_files: 26,
        children: [
          {
            foldername: "folder2.1.1",
            amount_of_files: 2,
            sum_children_files: 24,
            children: [
              {
                foldername: "folder2.1.1.1",
                amount_of_files: 24,
                sum_children_files: 0,
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        foldername: "folder2.2",
        amount_of_files: 5,
        sum_children_files: 0,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Consider, that I don't want to have the amount of files of the direct child on the parent. I want all following children of the branch on each node.

In my idea I need to reach the end of a branch and then somehow and that's my question, cycle back through the node to the parent and sum everything up and put each result on each node.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I updated the code as well.

Comment: Do you know how the `return` statement works?

Comment: I think so. Are you asking because I'm not returning anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map` instead of `.forEach`, so that you get a new array back, which should then be populated with new objects.

Note that there was a summing error in your example output, as the final folder with 5 items was not accumulated into the parent count (so it should be 34 instead of 29):

```js
const recur = (input) => input.map(node => {
    let children = recur(node.children);
    let sum_children_files = children.reduce((sum, child) => 
        sum + child.sum_children_files + child.amount_of_files
    , 0);
    return {...node, children, sum_children_files};
});

const data = [{foldername: "folder1",amount_of_files: 123,children: [{foldername: "folder1.1",amount_of_files: 3,children: [],},{foldername: "folder1.2",amount_of_files: 5,children: [{foldername: "folder1.2.1",amount_of_files: 20,children: [],},],},],},{foldername: "folder2",amount_of_files: 1,children: [{foldername: "folder2.1",amount_of_files: 3,children: [{foldername: "folder2.1.1",amount_of_files: 2,children: [{foldername: "folder2.1.1.1",amount_of_files: 24,children: [],},],},],},{foldername: "folder2.2",amount_of_files: 5,children: [],},],},];

const result = recur(data);

console.log(result);
```